# With Flask and Angular, how do I make $scope variables available to a python function

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I am kind of a beginner so I don't even know the best way to do this or what to call what I am trying to do, but I am making an event posting app which will have a header of the month and year like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boydjohnson/91byppwt/4/).

```
var calendar = angular.module('calendar', []);
calendar.controller('month_and_year', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.month = {{current_month}};
$scope.year = {{current_year}};
$scope.month_names = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
$scope.add_one = function () {
    if ($scope.month == 12) {
        $scope.year++;
        $scope.month = 1;
    } else {
        $scope.month++
    }
};
$scope.sub_one = function () {
    if ($scope.month == 1) {
        $scope.year--;
        $scope.month = 12;
    } else {
        $scope.month--
    }
};
}]);
```

The important part of my Python looks like this:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_month=now.month
current_year=now.year

def get_days_for_dates(year):
    dates = calendar.Calendar().yeardayscalendar(year)
    days_of_week=   ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    dates_list=[]
    days_list=[]
    for quarter in dates:
        for month in quarter:
            for week in month:
                for i in range(len(week)):
                    dates_list.append(week[i])
                    days_list.append(days_of_week[i])
    return days_list, dates_list

calendar_tuple = get_days_for_dates(current_year)
```

So my problem is I want to use $scope.year in my Python where current_year is to use the calendar module and come up with what day of the week each date is on.  What is the best approach to get this information to the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use an AJAX request the data back to server. This has two pieces:

The first is creating an endpoint on the backend which allows you to send the request and retrieves the data payload.

```
@app.route('/day-lookup', method=['GET'])
def day_lookup():
    year = request.args.get('year', None)
    # error handle here

    calendar_tuple = get_days_for_dates(year)
    # do something with it, return the list, etc.
```

The second piece is using Angular to send along the data and deal with the response.

```
var calendar = angular.module('calendar', []);
calendar.controller('month_and_year', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.month = {{current_month}};
$scope.year = {{current_year}};
$scope.month_names = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
$scope.add_one = function () {
    if ($scope.month == 12) {
        $scope.year++;
        $scope.month = 1;
    } else {
        $scope.month++
    }
};
$scope.sub_one = function () {
    if ($scope.month == 1) {
        $scope.year--;
        $scope.month = 12;
    } else {
        $scope.month--
    }
};
$scope.send_year = function () {
    // Add the year as a parameter to GET request to your URL
    var url = "http://foo.com/?year=" + $scope.year;
    // Send info to the server, then handle the result
    $http.get(url).then(function (result) {
        // Do something with the result
    });
};
}]);
```